# Trimming datatable entries from select

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I have the following code:

```
DataTable usersAndPhones = new DataTable();
using (var comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, PhoneNumber FROM Users", conn))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        usersAndPhones.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
    }
    catch
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Some `PhoneNumber`s from the database come with white spaces in the numbers (they are strings). What's the best way to trim them?

Comment: `string.Trim` or `string.Replace` (or the equivalent in the SQL itself).

Comment: you can use `TRIM()` in the `SELECT` statement if your DB provider supports it

Comment: Leading and trailing spaces or also between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just remove the spaces in front and rear of the string then use this

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(PhoneNumber)) as 'PhoneNumber'
```

e.g.

`SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM('  33 5 5  ')) as 'PhoneNumber'`   will return > '33 5 5'

-OR-

Use REPLACE function in SQL like this, it will replace all white spaces in your string.

```
DataTable usersAndPhones = new DataTable();
using (var comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, REPLACE(PhoneNumber , ' ', '') as 'PhoneNumber' FROM Users", conn))
try
{
    conn.Open();
    usersAndPhones.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
}
```

`SELECT REPLACE('  33 5 5  ', ' ','') as 'PhoneNumber'`   will return > '3355'

Comment: That will replace all spaces including ones in the middle.  Op just asked for trimming at beginning and end.  The title says TRIMMING.

Comment: he also says "white spaces in the numbers" so I assumed he needs the space to go away between the numbers.

Comment: With SQL-Server 2017 you can use `TRIM`

Comment: Correct, but he did not mention the version so I provided which works in all version.

Comment: Another way without using sql would be to enumerate the rows: `foreach(DataRow r in usersAndPhones) r.SetField("PhoneNumber",r.Field<string>("PhoneNumber").Trim())`

Comment: I think, the way he asked a simple question which can be easily googled, he is in learning mode and would be better to provide a simplest solution. He, of course, can learn other many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The `TRIM()` function will remove whitespace the beginning and end of a string:

`SELECT TRIM(PhoneNumber) as 'PhoneNumber' ...`